# flutter package for trim audio

Tags: flutter, audio, trim

I am trying to create a flutter app with trim audio. For that, I am looking for a library to trim a audio like [video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer).

I have tried the [audiocutter](https://pub.dev/packages/audiocutter) package. But the package is old and it's use [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package.

But In my app used [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) package for video trimming. So I can't use [audiocutter](https://pub.dev/packages/audiocutter) package.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following FFmpegKit command to cut audio.

```
double start = 1;
double end = 5;

var cmd = "-y -i \"$path\" -vn -ss $start -to $end -ar 16k -ac 2 -b:a 96k -acodec copy $outPath";

FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmd, (session) async {
    
    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    print("returnCode $returnCode");

});
```